# Why does TeamCity build occasionally fail with "Fail to update ... (LOCK_FAILURE)"?

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build that occasionally fails with the following error:

> Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS repository '*"MyVCSRoot"* {instance id=25, parent internal id=4, parent id=*MyBuild_MyVCSRoot*, description: "git@github.com:MyOrg/*MyRepository*.git#refs/heads/master"}'
>   'git fetch' command failed.
>   stderr: Fail to update 'refs/heads/*MyBranch*' (LOCK_FAILURE).
>   exit code: 1

Relevant details:
- "Occasionally fails" means that the build does run successfully most of the time.
- TeamCity version is v9.1.7, running on Windows.
- The build configuration only has one VCS root called *"MyVCSRoot"*.
- The VCS Root points to a private Git repo hosted on GitHub and authenticates using SSH.
- The VCS Checkout Mode is *"Automatically on agent (if supported by VCS roots)"*.

**UPDATE:** I think this might be a clue:

> [14:58:31]Collecting changes in 2 VCS roots (21s)
>   [14:58:31][Collecting changes in 2 VCS roots] VCS Root details
>   [14:58:31][VCS Root details] "*MyVCSRoot*" {instance id=32, parent internal id=4, parent id=*MyBuild_MyVCSRoot*, description: "git@github.com:*****/*****.git#refs/heads/master"}
>   [14:58:31][VCS Root details] "*AnotherVCSRoot*" {instance id=2, parent internal id=1, parent id=*AnotherBuild_AnotherVCSRoot*, description: "https://github.com/*****/*****.git#refs/heads/master"}

But why does my build use the other VCS root from another build?

Comment: The error can be caused by the remote git server updating the same ref in
the same repository. Please check if GitHub logs contain something about this error, also please check if there are any warnings about ref locks before the error in teamcity-vcs.log.